# 45-degree Side Load to Basement-level Garage

Tags: garage

My site plan is very tight between houses, so I cannot build on the sides of my house. I would like to put a side load garage behind/below my house - on the same level as my basement (will require some excavation and driveway sloping work. I also plan on a 1st level addition above the garage).  I also don't have a ton of room behind my house to have enough of space for a 90 degree side load garage (with needing to extend the driveway for the turn around space when leaving the garage). I currently have a 30 x 24 foot small cape cod house with a 12 foot wide driveway on the side.

I have seen **45 degree side load**/entry garages (instead of a 90 degree) - which are inline with the house (mainly in San Francisco). This allows for the car to enter the garage on an angle and not really need the turn-around space - one can simply back out of the garage and back-up the street or driveway.

I am trying to figure out the right dimensions I need for this (looking for only a 1 car garage size). I can't find any examples online. I need to have enough of a turn radius to clear my house's corner - but am not sure what that clearance should be.

Any help that can be provided on basic measurements (min size of garage (for SUV) to make this work, turning radius/clearance needed, etc) would really help me out. (dimensions on the drawing are not right - just the idea of what I am looking to build). I want to be sure I have enough room behind my house to build this to the correct depth.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you could enlarge the dimension numbers to make them more readable, that would help. Even clicking to open the image in a new browser window and zooming in, they're pretty small. Also, what is the depth of the garage? That isn't listed on the drawing, and 12'10" is a very non-standard garage door size that would require a custom garage door be made. Don't know if that matters to you, but it will be a significant added expense.

Comment: 8 feet by 20 feet fits most cars - if you have an absurdly long SUV, 22 or 24 feet. If your lot is this tight and you want to garage your car, an absurdly long SUV might not be the right choice. Set up some traffic cones in a parking lot to test your turn radius.

Comment: If you are willing to back up (or down) the driveway, you don't need a turn around space regardless of garage configuration. Backing down may be the better of the two, it's unlikely to have cross traffic in your own driveway.

Comment: @FreeMan  The dimensions on the drawing are wrong - so trying to get more accurate dimensions thru the feedback/recommendations. :) The garage opening I have currently much wider than a garage door - it can always be narrowed when built - but its more the left hand turning radius  into the driveway that I am worried about. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks - thats a great idea!

Comment: I would rotate it 90 deg and make it a 1-1/2 wide but maybe I missed something.

Comment: I would seriously consider building an accurate scale model of the area in question and a scale model of the vehicle, then move the "vehicle" around on the "driveway" and into the garage. Check to see that you have _plenty_ of clearance. If it _just_ makes it, then you're pretty much guaranteed to hit the house on the left or fence on the right in real life because you'll never be that precise in your driving. Especially with screaming kids in the car when you're running late for work, practice, or whatever...